# Enabling syntax highlighting for LESS in Programmer's Notepad?

Tags: windows, css, syntax-highlighting, source-code

When I don't feel like firing up the Visual Studio behemoth, or when I don't have it installed, I always turn to [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/). It's an amazingly light and fast little text editor, with the special advantage that it is completely platform-native and conforms to standard UI conventions.
<sub>Therefore, please do not suggest that I consider using *other* text editors. I've already considered and rejected them because they do not use native UI controls. I like Programmer's Notepad, thank you very much.</sub>

Unfortunately, I've recently begun to learn, use, and love [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for all of my CSS coding needs, and it appears that Programmer's Notepad is not bundled with a syntax highlighting scheme for LESS.

Does anyone know if there is—by chance and good fortune—one already available somewhere on the web that some kind soul has tediously prepared?

If not, how can I go about writing one of my own? Is there a way to build on the existing CSS scheme?

It's also possible that any code coloring scheme designed for Scintilla-based editors will work, as Programmer's Notepad is based on the [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) control. If you know of a LESS highlighting scheme for Scintilla-based editors, and how to use that with Programmer's Notepad, please suggest that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [instructions for adding a new Scheme](http://pnotepad.org/docs/howto/add_support_for_your_language) online.

And there are some additional [.scheme files available for download](http://www.pnotepad.org/add-ons/).

As there isn't a LESS one here, it would seem to be a good idea to base a new one on a close analogue, e.g. the existing CSS one, as you suggest.